# How to stop a running jar file in a bash script after 5 minutes and start the next one?

Tags: bash, java, jar

I have to run a jar file with different parameters like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/hawkarhama/Desktop/RUN 
echo $(java -jar IPM.jar 0 20 3 sign.txt)
echo $(java -jar IPM.jar 1 20 3 sign.txt)
echo $(java -jar IPM.jar 2 20 3 sign.txt)
```

If, say, the second one took more than five minutes, I want to stop it and continue to the next one. So the maximum time for each running jar is 5 minutes. If it takes less than that, that's fine; but if one runs longer than that, the script must continue to the next one.

Comment: (1) If you are asking *specifically* about a Java program that you can modify, one approach might be to build the time limit into the Java code. (2) Why do you say `echo $(…)` instead of just running the program with `java -jar IPM.jar … sign.txt`?

Comment: For the `echo$`you are right and I did that before that was just a copy of the code I putted here. As for the java code I don't know how to do that programmatically. I tried `System.CurrentTimeMilles` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in bash 4 or later:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/hawkarhama/Desktop/RUN 
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 300; kill $cmdpid ) & exec java -jar IPM.jar 0 20 3 sign.txt )
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 300; kill $cmdpid ) & exec java -jar IPM.jar 1 20 3 sign.txt )
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 300; kill $cmdpid ) & exec java -jar IPM.jar 2 20 3 sign.txt )
```

For previous versions:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/hawkarhama/Desktop/RUN 
bash -c '(sleep 300; kill $$) & exec java -jar IPM.jar 0 20 3 sign.txt'
bash -c '(sleep 300; kill $$) & exec java -jar IPM.jar 1 20 3 sign.txt'
bash -c '(sleep 300; kill $$) & exec java -jar IPM.jar 2 20 3 sign.txt'
```

After searching a bit for a pure java version, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2); 
final Future handler = executor.submit(new Callable(){ 
     DoStuffHere();
});
executor.schedule(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
         handler.cancel();
     }      
}, 5*60*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.It still runs the process after the 5 minutes . `kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`. It gives me this line after each process takes more than 5 minutes . and it still run it which is not what I want.

Comment: @Hk148: I got this to work, in a somewhat artificial test. (I got a `kill: (1234) - No such process` message for each invocation that finished before the time ran out.) Are you sure you're typing it correctly? (Try copying and pasting.) What operating system are you using?

Comment: This method has the dissadvantage of having the "kill process" and "no such process" output. I tried running it with a `2>&1 >/dev/null` after the kill command, but it did not omit the output, so for clarity, I omitted that on the solution. I tested it on cygwin, not on a truly unix shell, but arguments for commands like `kill` should be the same as most linux boxes

Comment: @G-Man I use Mac osx,but the problem is after the 5 minutes it won't start the next test, or the next line.after 5 minutes it just stops every thing.

Comment: @NuTTyX is there any other ways to do that in the java code?

Comment: Seems like Mac OS X has bash 3.2, so my first solution won't work. I have included a new one. Try it.

Comment: Just a warning: under the right conditions, this solution could kill the wrong process. If the process to be killed has exited, then its PID could be assigned to a different process. And some unix-y systems assign PIDs pseudo-randomly, so a PID could be recycled sooner than you expect it to be.

Comment: @Kenster true, but unlikely for not very busy servers and within that 5 minute timeout. Also, very ugly as it keeps printing "kill" output every time, but easiest as you do not need to edit the java code and relies on common commands. I have included a new solution that should be cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 1):

If your system has the `timeout` command, you should be able to use it, as

```
timeout 300s java -jar IPM.jar 0 20 3 sign.txt
    ︙
```

Comment: `man timeout` or `info coreutils 'timeout invocation'` to have a full help. It is a part of _GNU coreutils_.

Comment: @G-Man When I try this it says, `timeout: command not found`. I think this version can not find the timeout or I don't have it on my mac

Comment: @Hk148: Yeah, after NuTTyX figured out that your version of bash was too old to support his first answer, I was afraid that OS X would be missing this, too.